# What is the relation between the gaussian integral and the volume of the n-ball?

Tags: improper-integrals, area, pi

Even if I've red other threads treating this question, it's still obscure to me what deeply relates the multiple Guassian integral $\int e^{-x^2} = \sqrt \pi$ and the area of a $n$-ball.

Someone could offer an insight?

Comment: That step falls out of a more intuitive calculation - taking the Laplace transform (i.e. 'continuous' power series expansion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Relation_to_power_series ) of the volume http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.383.7614&rep=rep1&type=pdf then inverting by observation http://www.math.utah.edu/~gustafso/s2010/laplaceTableProofs.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\pi^{n/2} = \int \exp \left( -\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \right) \mathrm d V = \int_0^\infty \exp \left( -r^2 \right) r^{n-1} \mathrm d r \int \mathrm d \Omega.
$$
The second equality is change of cartesian coordinates into spherical and application of Fubini theorem. $\int \mathrm d \Omega$, which is also the surface of a sphere of $n-1$ dimensions of unitary radius, can be computed from this relation. This is because $\int_0^\infty \exp \left( -r^2 \right) r^{n-1} \mathrm d r = \frac 12\Gamma \left(\frac n 2 \right)$ and we know now to deal with [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Knowing how to compute $\int\mathrm d \Omega$ you can compute the volume easily. Once again using spherical coordinates and Fubini theorem
$$
\int_{r<R} \mathrm d V = \int_0^R r^{n-1} \mathrm d r  \int \mathrm d \Omega.
$$

Comment: Thank you. Just a question: $\int \mathrm d \Omega$ gives the surface area of a $(n-1)-$sphere of unitary $r$?

Comment: @LoScrondo Yes, you are right. I'll edit the answer to fix this.